# Conditional Entropy and Gibbs Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, information-theory, entropy

We know $$H(X | Y) + H(Y) = H(X, Y)$$
Therefore, $$H(X | Y) \leq H(X, Y) $$ since $$ H(Y) \geq 0$$
If we expand this out, we get
$$-\sum_{x,y} {p(x,y) \log p(x | y)} \leq - \sum_{x,y} {p(x,y) \log p(x, y)}$$

According to Gibbs inequality, the inequality should go in the other direction. What has gone wrong here?

Comment: I thought this was chemistry for a second! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  [Gibbs inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs%27_inequality), applied to the multivariate variable $(x,y)$, tell us that
$$- \sum_{x,y} {p(x,y) \log p(x, y)} \le - \sum_{x,y}{p(x,y) \log q(x, y)}  $$

where $q(x, y)$ is some arbitrary (multivariate) probability function. Namely, $q(x, y)\ge 0 $ and $ \sum_{x,y} q(x,y) =1$

But  $p(x\mid y)$ is not such a thing. Rather, for each fixed $y$ it's a one-dimensional (in $x$) probability function. That is, $ \sum_{x,y} p(x\mid y)= \sum_y \sum_x p(x\mid y) = \sum_y 1\ne 1$

Comment: I get your reasoning. But surely, we can also think of $$p(x|y)$$ as a one dimensional variable in y, in which case $$\sum_{x,y} {p(x|y)} = \sum_{x} \sum_{y} {p(x|y)} = \sum_{x} {p(x)} = 1$$

Comment: No,  we can't. $\sum_{y} {p(x|y)} \ne p(x)$